# How can I float text by text in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting

See the attached image below, which shows that a side-note is added so that the normal text of the document "floats around it":

1. How is that technique called - Is there a name for it?
2. And how can I accomplish that in Google Docs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called **text wrap** and you can do it in Google Docs for example like this:

[image: 0]

---

If you want to do it with text box instead of an image add Drawing (**Insert** > **Drawing...**)

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]